# I am getting "<ip address> was resolved to null" message while using SendArpRequest class from Pcap4j library. How to implement it properly?

Tags: java, sockets, arp, pcap4j

I am trying to get MAC address of the device in a local network by using its IP address. To implement this in java I found a library name Pcap4j. I am using its class SendArpRequest to generate ARP request and receive a reply, but it always says "IP-Address was resolved to null".

Here is the java code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import org.pcap4j.core.BpfProgram.BpfCompileMode;
    import org.pcap4j.core.NotOpenException;
    import org.pcap4j.core.PacketListener;
    import org.pcap4j.core.PcapHandle;
    import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNativeException;
    import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface;
    import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface.PromiscuousMode;
    import org.pcap4j.core.Pcaps;
    import org.pcap4j.packet.ArpPacket;
    import org.pcap4j.packet.EthernetPacket;
    import org.pcap4j.packet.Packet;
    import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.ArpHardwareType;
    import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.ArpOperation;
    import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.EtherType;
    import org.pcap4j.util.ByteArrays;
    import org.pcap4j.util.MacAddress;
    import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public class SendArpRequest {

    private static final String COUNT_KEY = SendArpRequest.class.getName() + ".count";
    private static final int COUNT = Integer.getInteger(COUNT_KEY, 1);

    private static final String READ_TIMEOUT_KEY = SendArpRequest.class.getName() + ".readTimeout";
    private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = Integer.getInteger(READ_TIMEOUT_KEY, 10); // [ms]

    private static final String SNAPLEN_KEY = SendArpRequest.class.getName() + ".snaplen";
    private static final int SNAPLEN =Integer.getInteger(SNAPLEN_KEY, 65536); // [bytes]

    private static final MacAddress SRC_MAC_ADDR =MacAddress.getByName("00:db:df:8b:b1:a9");

    private static MacAddress resolvedAddr;

    private SendArpRequest() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PcapNativeException, NotOpenException {
    String strSrcIpAddress = "192.168.0.11"; // for InetAddress.getByName()
    //String strDstIpAddress = args[0]; // for InetAddress.getByName()
    String strDstIpAddress = "192.168.0.3"; // for InetAddress.getByName()


    System.out.println(COUNT_KEY + ": " + COUNT);
    System.out.println(READ_TIMEOUT_KEY + ": " + READ_TIMEOUT);
    System.out.println(SNAPLEN_KEY + ": " + SNAPLEN);
    System.out.println("\n");

    PcapNetworkInterface nif;
    try {
          nif = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
    } catch (IOException e){ 
           e.printStackTrace();
            return;
    }

    if (nif == null) {
       return;
    }

    System.out.println(nif.getName() + "(" + nif.getDescription() + ")");

    PcapHandle handle = nif.openLive(SNAPLEN,         PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS, READ_TIMEOUT);
    PcapHandle sendHandle = nif.openLive(SNAPLEN, PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS, READ_TIMEOUT);
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    try {
      handle.setFilter(
      "arp and src host "
          + strDstIpAddress
          + " and dst host "
          + strSrcIpAddress
          + " and ether dst "
          + Pcaps.toBpfString(SRC_MAC_ADDR),
      BpfCompileMode.OPTIMIZE);

      PacketListener listener =
      new PacketListener() {
        public void gotPacket(Packet packet) {
          if (packet.contains(ArpPacket.class)) {
            ArpPacket arp = packet.get(ArpPacket.class);
            if (arp.getHeader().getOperation().equals(ArpOperation.REPLY)) {
              SendArpRequest.resolvedAddr = arp.getHeader().getSrcHardwareAddr();
            }
          }
          System.out.println(packet);
        }
      };

    Task t = new Task(handle, listener);
    pool.execute(t);

    ArpPacket.Builder arpBuilder = new ArpPacket.Builder();
    try {
    arpBuilder
        .hardwareType(ArpHardwareType.ETHERNET)
        .protocolType(EtherType.IPV4)
        .hardwareAddrLength((byte) MacAddress.SIZE_IN_BYTES)
        .protocolAddrLength((byte) ByteArrays.INET4_ADDRESS_SIZE_IN_BYTES)
        .operation(ArpOperation.REQUEST)
        .srcHardwareAddr(SRC_MAC_ADDR)
        .srcProtocolAddr(InetAddress.getByName(strSrcIpAddress))
        .dstHardwareAddr(MacAddress.ETHER_BROADCAST_ADDRESS)
        .dstProtocolAddr(InetAddress.getByName(strDstIpAddress));
          } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
          }

    EthernetPacket.Builder etherBuilder = new EthernetPacket.Builder();
  etherBuilder
      .dstAddr(MacAddress.ETHER_BROADCAST_ADDRESS)
      .srcAddr(SRC_MAC_ADDR)
      .type(EtherType.ARP)
      .payloadBuilder(arpBuilder)
      .paddingAtBuild(true);

            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
              Packet p = etherBuilder.build();
              System.out.println(p);
              sendHandle.sendPacket(p);
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
             }
            }
        } finally {
          if (handle != null && handle.isOpen()) {
            handle.close();
          }
          if (sendHandle != null && sendHandle.isOpen()) {
            sendHandle.close();
          }
          if (pool != null && !pool.isShutdown()) {
            pool.shutdown();
          }

    System.out.println(strDstIpAddress + " was resolved to " + resolvedAddr);
               }
            }

    private static class Task implements Runnable {

    private PcapHandle handle;
    private PacketListener listener;

    public Task(PcapHandle handle, PacketListener listener) {
    this.handle = handle;
    this.listener = listener;
    }

        public void run() {
          try {
            handle.loop(COUNT, listener);
          } catch (PcapNativeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (NotOpenException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And I got this output by using sourceIP = "192.168.0.11", sourceMAC = "00:db:df:8b:b1:a9" and destinationIP = "192.168.0.3".

```
    com.arpscan.SendArpRequest.count: 1
    com.arpscan.SendArpRequest.readTimeout: 10
    com.arpscan.SendArpRequest.snaplen: 65536


    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder                                 for further details.
    6
    6
    7
    2
    2
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    NIF[0]: wlp1s0
          : link layer address: 00:db:df:8b:b1:a9
          : address: /192.168.0.11
          : address: /fe80:0:0:0:c090:df9:7448:e0be
    NIF[1]: any
          : description: Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces
    NIF[2]: lo
          : link layer address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
          : address: /127.0.0.1
          : address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
    NIF[3]: virbr0
          : link layer address: 52:54:00:72:e9:70
          : address: /192.168.122.1
    NIF[4]: enp0s31f6
          : link layer address: 50:7b:9d:cc:71:d2
    NIF[5]: bluetooth0
          : description: Bluetooth adapter number 0
    NIF[6]: nflog
          : description: Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface
    NIF[7]: nfqueue
          : description: Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface
    NIF[8]: usbmon1
          : description: USB bus number 1
    NIF[9]: usbmon2
          : description: USB bus number 2

    Select a device number to capture packets, or enter 'q' to quit > 0
    wlp1s0(null)
    [Ethernet Header (14 bytes)]
      Destination address: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      Source address: 00:db:df:8b:b1:a9
      Type: 0x0806 (ARP)
    [ARP Header (28 bytes)]
      Hardware type: 1 (Ethernet (10Mb))
      Protocol type: 0x0800 (IPv4)
      Hardware address length: 6 [bytes]
      Protocol address length: 4 [bytes]
      Operation: 1 (REQUEST)
      Source hardware address: 00:db:df:8b:b1:a9
      Source protocol address: /192.168.0.11
      Destination hardware address: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      Destination protocol address: /192.168.0.3
    [Ethernet Pad (18 bytes)]
      Hex stream: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

    [data (42 bytes)]
      Hex stream: 00 db df 8b b1 a9 d0 04 01 62 61 38 08 06 00 01 08 00 06 04 00 02 d0 04 01 62 61 38 c0 a8 00 03 00 db df 8b b1 a9 c0 a8 00 0b

    192.168.0.3 was resolved to null
```

Here I got null for destination MAC Address as you can see.

But when I run arp-scan command I got correct MAC address for the given IP Address. Here is screenshot of arp-scan result.

[image: arp-scan result]

Please suggest me how I can implement it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a packet factory moudle (e.g. pcap4j-packetfactory-static.jar) to your class path so that Pcap4J can dessect the ARP response.

And, probably you'd better add `volatile` to `private static MacAddress resolvedAddr;`.